# Why was Billy Crudup not credited in "The Watch"?

Tags: casting, credits, the-watch

In [*The Watch* (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1298649/), Billy Crudup plays a creepy neighbor. He has a lot of dialog, and several important/pivotal scenes in which he directly interacts with the main characters. Why was he not credited in the movie? ([IMDB only shows his name](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1298649/) in a special "uncredited" cast list.)

Comment: Best guess is that his role was a cameo but with load of improv that they decided to keep in the film

Comment: @Richard That question makes me sick every time I see it :P

Comment: @Catija - It is a bit broad and blanketing, I admit. That's why I thought I'd leave it to others to drop the hammer